# CSS ul and li class conflict

Tags: html, css

I have a main navigation bar on my website. And I want to add another sub-menu on every page with the different styling. But, the ul & li are conflicting and the main navigation is also getting messy.

Here's the html & css of sub-navigation. 
How can I skip the conflict?
Maybe by renaming the ul and li to something else?

***HTML***

```
<ul><li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>
Portfolio
<ul>
<li>Web Design</li>
<li>Web Development</li>
<li>Illustrations</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #555;
color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
background: #555; 
display: block; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
```

Comment: please provide the fiddle url

Comment: check whether u closed all the tages

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n9z5D/1141/

Comment: I've closed all the tags. But the main navigation is also having ul and li, and the classes are conflicting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yqd6c6fc/ this is the fiddle link based on ur code. Where u are see conflicting ?

Comment: I want to give a class name to this css. How to do it?

Comment: check my answer, I added styles using css class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use classes. For example:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
<li>Item</li>
<li><ul class="submenu">
    <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Then you could use them in CSS:

```
.mainmenu > li {
color: red;
}
```

- .mainmenu would affect only the main ul
- .mainmenu > li would affect only the main items
- .submenu would affect only the submenu ul
- .submenu > li would affect only the submenu items

Comment: Can you please mention that how may i define class with ul and li in css?
Assuming any class name.

Comment: You can use .mainmenu or .submenu to refer to the main ul or the secundary one. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Got it. But what about: ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; }

How to mention a class for this?

Comment: .submenu > li { background: #555; }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oyp6qkyz/ 
That's what I've achieved, can you please make the markup correct?

Comment: Perfect! But the dropdown menu styles are not loading.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp to learn how to use classes and CSS selectors

Comment: How should they look?

Comment: Changed CSS line 11 from ".rexademenu  > li"  to ".rexademenu   li"

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul><li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>
Portfolio
<ul>
```

You don't close the li after Portfolio

Edit : Ooops, I missed the closing tag. But please indent your code properly.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your HTML markup with this code

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Web Design</li>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```